# Use Apache velocity 1.7 or 2.0 in Java application without Maven

Tags: java, osgi, velocity, eclipse-pde, apache-velocity

Can someone detail the steps to use the Velocity templating engine in Java plugin project without using Maven for building and resolving dependencies.

I would like to download the required plugins/dependencies manually and package them part of my plugin.
At the end I want the bare minimum functionality of generating rendered files based on templates and some log files as a result.
I am not looking for how to start the engine, creating context, loading template files or file creation.
Rather how to set up the environment which contains the velocity engine ready to be used in the plugin development environment in eclipse.

All the examples I found online suggested using Maven for resolving dependencies which is not possible in my case due to the in-place build infrastructure in my team.

Comment: Have you check out the dependency page? http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.2/dependencies.html If that's not enough, I would create a minimal maven project, check the dependency tree and add all libraries to the build-process.

Comment: I just checked it, for version 1.7 there is a jar file named velocity-1.7-dep.jar and in version 2.0 slf4j-api and commons-lang specified as dependencies.
In both the above cases I downloaded the dependencies and specified them in the manfiest file->runtime tab.
But when I try to execute I get the exception: 
"org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Error initializing log: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute with the current runtime configuration".

Comment: Eclipse Orbit contains velocity 1.5 if that helps you https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20200529191137/ (assuming you use a target platform, since you mentioned Eclipse PDE)